# ng-click behaving weird with ng-repeat on android kitkat 4.4.4

Tags: android, angularjs

I came across a very peculiar while testing my code on android.
Am able to reproduce this issue only in android version 4.4.4.(been able to reproduce in every device which has kit kat 4.4.4)

What am trying to do:
there's a page which allows a user to select security questions .
Am fetching the question list from a JSON file.
on that JSON object am using ng-repeat to get radio buttons for all the questions.
in addition to that we have a input button corresponding to every every question.
which are basically hidden from user view and we only show them once the user has clicked on the corresponding radio button
rest all input fields remain hidden.

Have achieved this using basic ng-hide/show directive

based on the fact that as soon as the user clicks on the radio button the corresponding input field will show.

And then comes a submit button outside the ng-repeat directive scope which simply takes us to the next page.

now the issue is that if I select the first radio button and enter anything and then click on the submit button without taking the focus out of the input field .
Nothing happens . It simply takes the focus out of the input box. on next click it works fine.
Even weirder the functionality seems to work fine for the last radio option.

below is the required html section code.

```
    <form>
                <fieldset>
                    <div ng-repeat="question in  sortedQuestion1">

                        <label for="optionsRadios.{{$index}}" class="radio radio modal-form marTop20">
                            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios.{{$index}}"
                                   value="{{question.QuestionId}}" ng-model="SeqQuestions.firstQuestionId"
                                   ng-click="clickSet=true;SeqQuestions.securityAnswer1=''; showRadio($index)"/>

                            <i class="skin"></i>
                            <span ng-bind-html="question.QuestionText"></span>
                        </label>

                        <div class="checkbox-content hide" id="showText{{$index}}"
                             ng-class="{'showText{{$index}}': 'show','': 'hide'}[radioFlag]">
                            <div class="form-row"
                                <label for="{{$index}}"><span ng-bind-html="content.Security_Question.Label"/></label>

                                <div class="field-group">
                                    <input id="{{$index}}" class="span3" type="text"
                                           ng-model="SeqQuestions.securityAnswer1"
                                           name="securityAnswer1"
                                           ng-dirty="clickSet=false;"/>

                                    <button class="reset-field reset hide-text" type="button"
                                            ng-click="clickSet=true;SeqQuestions.securityAnswer1='';">Reset field
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="content-pad">
            <button class="btn " id="nextQestion" role="button" ng-init="clickSet=true"
                    ng-disabled="!SeqQuestions.securityAnswer1" ng-click="nextSecurityQ()"><span ng-bind-html="content.Security_Question.NextQuestion.Label"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="btn " role="button" ng-mousedown="cancelLink()" ng-bind-html="content.Common_Elements..Cancel.Label"></a>
        </div>

    </form>



             $scope.nextSecurityQ = function () {
                  $log.info("updateSecurityQuesCtrl : inside method");              
                  $location.url("/securityQuestion2");


        };
```

Am totally out of clues as to why this is happening.
Any help is higly appriciated

Comment: I remember something similar happening in one of my apps. Some suggestions: Change the button tag of your submitt button to a <div>. Or add type="submit" to your submit button. It may also have to do with the virtual keyboard of Android Devices with 4.4.x... a tap on the submit button would first close the keyboard and only the second one would actually submit.